# Quick way to find common words between two strings

Tags: php, string

I have a string which has the length of an average sentence, it can be made up of any random words. I also have a file (around 600kb) which contains some more random words.

I want to find out the common words between these two as efficiently as possible. Right now, I am going over two loops to match each word from the string against each word in the file but that seems a bit inefficient. Is there a better and more efficient way to get the common words?

Comment: move the file to a db, break the sentence in to words, query the db

Comment: Not quite a dup, but [this might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494249/extracting-the-common-words-between-two-paragraphs?rq=1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load one set into an array keys (values can be anything). Then loop the other set and test whether the array has those keys. This way you don't have two nested loops, but two independent ones (load loop and test loop), and key lookup is easy and fast when compared to the value lookup.

If you are testing multiple sentences against one file, loading the file into the array is clearly better. If your file is larger than your memory (shouldn't happen really, not with 600kb), then do it the other way around.

Alternately you can just make two arrays, then use `array_intersect` or `array_intersect_key`. If PHP is smart, `array_intersect_keys` will use the above procedure; in any case it should be good because it is implemented in C. The downside is you must load everything into memory (again, probably not an issue).

Comment: Thanks  @Amandan. Do the arrays have to be associative arrays?

Comment: Using `array_intersection_key` returns the whole sentence while `array_intersect` only returns common words.

Answer (score 0):

Your current algorithm complexity is O(N*M). To improve it, you can use hashtable to store the words from the file. In PHP, associative arrays are implemented as hashtables. So your array will look like this

```
$array = ['abc' => true, 'dfg' => true, ]// and so on
```

and use `array_key_exists` to check if word is in array. This gives you O(1) on validation. And finally, you have to iterate the words in your sentences. It will be O(N), where N is a number of words. Final complexity is O(N)